# Is there a way I can export productivity reports based on Outlook appointments?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, productivity, tasks

I'm being asked to keep track of what tasks I'm working on for every hour of the day.

The first thing I thought of was using a `stopwatch` application. Failed miserably.
I then started filling out an Excel sheet. After 2 weeks I stopped filling it and lost track again.

Then I thought: Half of my schedule is on Outlook already because meetings. So, the best thing I could do is to fill out the other half and use some tool to export a Excel report.

Can I do that?

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: This is a couple years old, but it may be useful to you - [Use Outlook as an automatic time tracking tool](http://www.itworld.com/article/2714516/consumerization/use-outlook-as-an-automatic-time-tracking-tool.html)